# Where does Websphere get the WSDL from?

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, websphere

I have a java application that has Web Services published using Axis.

With the latest release one of the service methods in the WSDL is wrong.  It has a field in a complex type with double instead of an array of doubles.

I've checked the src WSDL and the generated classes like the data object and the binding stub, but they are all correct.

However, when I browse to the WSDL it is different.

I can see other differences.  For example, the source is just a complex type with a sequence where the published version extends an abstract base.

So were is Websphere getting this other WSDL from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I expect the WSDL is being automatically generated using the Axis Java2WSDL tools. I believe you can choose to turn off the automatic generation or add some directives to generate the kind of WSDL you would prefer.