# WebSphere modifies my WSDL when deploying a web service (JAX-WS)

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, websphere, jax-ws

Whenever I deploy my web service (as a .WAR) in WebSphere (using the administrator console), it seems to modify its WSDL to separate it into a WSDL and a XSD (basically removing the inlining of the WSDL types). It also renames it GetGedDoc.wsdl (original name is GetGedDocumentService.wsdl).

I don't have any real issue with that specifically, but the XSD rename all the parameters arg0, arg1, etc... and make them all optional.

How to prevent this quite annoying behavior?

I don't really see what code you could use to diagnostic the issue, but here's my WSDL anyway.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!-- Generated by JAX-WS RI (http://jax-ws.java.net). 
    RI's version is JAX-WS RI 2.2.10 svn-revision#IBM 2.2.10-12/21/2015 12:33:25 
    PM(foreman)-. -->
<definitions xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" name="GetGedDocumentService"
    targetNamespace="http://cm.web.dsidiff.fr/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
    xmlns:tns="http://cm.web.dsidiff.fr/" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata"
    xmlns:wsp="http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy" xmlns:wsp1_2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy"
    xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <types>
        <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://cm.web.dsidiff.fr/">
            <xsd:element name="parameters" type="tns:getDocument"/>
            <xsd:complexType name="getDocument">
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="1" name="pid" type="xsd:string" />
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="1" name="login" type="xsd:string" />
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="1" name="pwd" type="xsd:string" />
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="1" name="numClient" type="xsd:string" />
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="numCompte" type="xsd:string" />
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="itemType" type="xsd:string" />
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="typeDoc" type="xsd:string" />
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:element name="result" type="xsd:string" />
        </xsd:schema>
    </types>
    <message name="getDocument">
        <part element="tns:parameters" name="parameters" />
    </message>
    <message name="getDocumentResponse">
        <part element="tns:result" name="result" />
    </message>
    <portType name="GetGedDocService">
        <operation name="getDocument">
            <input message="tns:getDocument"/>
            <output message="tns:getDocumentResponse" />
        </operation>
    </portType>
    <binding name="GetGedDocSOAP" type="tns:GetGedDocService">
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
        <operation name="getDocument">
            <soap:operation soapAction="http://localhost:9080/DSI_CMDK_WS/getDocument" />
            <input>
                <soap:body use="literal" />
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap:body use="literal" />
            </output>
        </operation>
    </binding>
    <service name="GetGedDocService">
        <port binding="tns:GetGedDocSOAP" name="GetGedDocSOAP">
            <soap:address location="http://localhost:9080" />
        </port>
    </service>
</definitions>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/238643/where-does-websphere-get-the-wsdl-from?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of possibilities.  If your @Webservice annotation does not include a wsdlLocation attribute, then WebSphere doesn't know about your wsdl and is generating one.

When  wsdl is packaged with the application, WebSphere will examine it and compare it to the code.  If it's incompatible with the code for some reason (operations or parameters don't match,  or namespaces are mismatched, etc.) then it will be ignored and another one will be generated.

If it's leaning towards the second one, a trace of com.ibm.ws.websvcs.*=all might be informative.

Comment: That makes sense! How would I go about "tracing com.ibm.ws.websvcs.*=all"? I'm quite inexperienced with Eclipse/Rational/WebSphere.

Comment: In the admin console, troubleshooting ->logs and trace ->(server) -> change detail levels, select the "runtime" tab, change *=info to *=info:com.ibm.ws.websvcs.*=all.  Select the checkbox "save changes to config" if you want this to stick across a server restart.  Click Ok, click save.   Output will be in trace.log